# Adding Cc to PHP mail

Tags: php, email, post

So I am mailing the contents of a form to a client and he would like the person who sent the form to be Cc'd in.

I have done some research and it appears I need to use the `header` code to set the from, subject and cc but my code is set up differently - please see below:

```
<?php
$relatedproduct = $_POST['related-product'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$formcontent="From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n About: $relatedproduct \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "email@mydomain.com";
$subject = "More information regarding $relatedproduct";

$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

Would it be possible to do it like this?

```
<?php
$relatedproduct = $_POST['related-product'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "More information regarding $relatedproduct";
$formcontent="From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n About: $relatedproduct \n Message: $message";


$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";


// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $formcontent, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: check out http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Comment: yes.. The CC is  like you are written.

Comment: Why you don't try to use PHPMailer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[php.net/mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Yes, as you have it:

```
...
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthday@example.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
?>
```

Incidentally, please sanitise your POST variables before you inject them (e.g. `$to = $_POST['email'];`).

As @Rhopercy says in their comment, perhaps an email library will help you as it takes care of most things for you. Take a look at [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [SwiftMail](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
    $relatedproduct = $_POST['related-product'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$headers = "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email";
$headers .= 'Cc: test@test.com\r\n';
$headers .= 'Bcc: test@test.com\r\n';
$headers .= "Return-Path: <info@premierinspectiontn.com>\r\n";

$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "More information regarding $relatedproduct";
$formcontent="From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n About: $relatedproduct \n Message: $message";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $formcontent, $headers);
```